# Visual Studio 2017 compiling c++17 file via cmake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, c++17, project

Let's try compiling this `test.cpp`

```
int main(){
    if (not(1 == 0)) 
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

with *Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017* (Version 15.9.15) using this `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)    
project ("Test")    
add_executable (Test "test.cpp")
target_compile_features(Test PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
set_target_properties(Test PROPERTIES CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

This will not compile on my Windows 10 machine, because `not` is undefined. I tried [other examples](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/features/cpp11.html), too. It simply does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can manually check if you have the right standard https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2019

Comment: Yes, this is true (and helpful), *if* VS recognizes a cmake-project as a *project*. This means, that if you click New and select cmake-project, VS happily creates everything and so on, but won't offer you project options (via rightlick).

Comment: `not` is not a feature of C++17. It's ancient, dating from the time when some keyboards didn't have all punctuation characters, and so some people couldn't type `!`. Your code doesn't use any C++17-specific features (or indeed anything that C++98 compiler wouldn't recognize). Whatever problem you have is not related to the version of the standard. Can you show the text of whatever error messages you receive?

Comment: Oh dear.. I honestly thought the opposite was the case: `Not` was recently introduced to make codes more readable. I'm going to have a look at this tomorrow. Thanks a ton for pointing this out.

Comment: It's still not working while using `not`. (`not` is not defined.) Things like `auto` work in a VS '17 CMake-Project though. 

*But* `not` **is** working in a normal C++-project. That's strange. Can anybody confirm this?